# AppStore Versioning

Tags: ios, app-store

I'm planning to release an iOS app soon, just to speed up the AppStore Review process I want to start it earlier. I want to understand the versioning concept there.

Assume that I sent 1.0.0 to review and it's approved and ready for release (But I won't release this version).
If I send a new version, can it be still 1.0.0 or it has to be sth like 1.0.1 or 1.1.0?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**On AppStore** - you can add build numbers and the version can be the same.

**On Google Play** - each version has to be a different version number (even when version has not released).

Comment: Is it possible to start with 0.9.0, then 1.0.0 for final one?

Comment: Yes, you can choose any version number. Just be sure that the next version will be higher.

Comment: Not sure about Build Numbers will help for AppStore..

Comment: Build number increase each time you upload to AppStore (even when you won't release the version), but the version is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can reject it yourself and still use the display version 1.0.0 with a different build version.

Comment: But it would start the review process from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

If version 1.0.0 is still pending review, you can reject it yourself, apply a newer 1.0.0 build and resubmit for review.

Once version 1.0.0 has been approved you would need to increase the version number, even if you never released it to the App Store, so 1.0.1, or similar would be required.

These days App Store review typically takes less than 24 hours, so you can set up all of your meta data, screenshots etc and simply upload the build and submit for review once you are happy with the code.